# Is it ok to delete all files and folders in ec2-user directory in Amazon-EC2 linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-ec2

My first time using Amazon-EC2 and NodeJS. After a day of playing the ec2-user directory looks messy since I was trying to install packages in wrong folders.

I want to delete everything and start anew.

Is it ok to delete everything in ec2-user directory or some files needs to be kept?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm also sort of a newbie linux user.

Comment: You could just wipe out your box and start fresh. That's part of the beauty of the cloud--easy to start fresh from an image anytime you want.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is create a new user, which would also create a new directory for that user.

```
home
  |_ec2-user
  |_newuser
```

When I created the newuser the system created these files:

> .bash_history, .bash_logout, .bash_profile, .bashrc

So I guess these are the files that should stay (my guess is even if you delete them the system supposed to re-create them automatically, but it's better that they stay to be on the safe side). I deleted everything except for these files in my original ec2-user directory and it seems to be fine.

Also very important this directory must stay too .ssh - it contains authorized_keys file that holds a key-pair and is needed for SSH access.